# Binary logistic regression to correct OR for mortality associated with a condition

Tags: logistic, binary-data, odds-ratio, medicine

I'm analyzing the results from a 20 patients prospective study and what I'm trying to do is to correct the odds ratio for bad outcome associated with the presence of atrial fibrillation for the severity of the patients conditions (measured by SOFA score).  In order to do so I performed binary logistic regression with, as dependent variable the outcome of the patient and, as covariates I put the intersection between atrial fibrillation and the severity score SOFA.  The numbers seems fine since the ExpB that comes out is 1,208, which is consistent with previous literature about the topic, but I'm not sure about the procedure I used to obtain it.  Could you please confirm me I used the test appropriately?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the intersection of AF and SOFA? Did you put in both variables as binary covariates, both plus their interaction, one covariate with two levels (a) both AF and SOAF+ (b) one or neither of AF and SOFA+?

Comment: the AF variable is binary (present or not), the SOFA score, on the other hand, is a scale from 0 to 25 according to the patient's clinical condition. i put in the model both variable on their own plus their interaction, which is what i'm really interested about.

Comment: In that case your model seems appropriate.